# How do you make a nested right facing arrow in a font?

Tags: html, fonts

Not <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd>, but like a file hierachy right angle to signify a nested document in a folder

looks something similar to the capital letter "L" but with equal lengths and the center lin in the middle of the font height?

or the vertical inverse of this: ↵ (so that it is pointing right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type it into your text and make sure that you're storing the text in unicode? ↳

Or encode it as an entity ↳ (Which is `&#x21B3;`)